# In all case i am getting values for shape and hyd as 0

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

it is a python tkinter code.. I am not able to retain values. always I am getting 0

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

myWindow = tk.Tk()
myWindow.title("DESIGN OF LINED CANAL")
v1=IntVar()

Label(myWindow,text="What is the shape of your Canal? ").pack()

R1=Radiobutton(myWindow,text="Trapezoidal",variable=v1,value=0).pack()
R2=Radiobutton(myWindow,text="Rectangular",variable=v1,value=1).pack()
R3=Radiobutton(myWindow,text="Triangular",variable=v1,value=2).pack()
shape=v1.get()


v2=IntVar()
Radiobutton(myWindow,text="Yes",variable=v2,value=0).pack()
Radiobutton(myWindow,text="No",variable=v2,value=1).pack()
hyd=v2.get()

Button(myWindow,text="OK",bg="red",command=myWindow.destroy).pack()
myWindow.mainloop()
print("shape",shape)
print("hyd",hyd)
```

Comment: Please add your code as text, do not post a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are running into is the fact that when your code does `get()` it is only being run the instant your code starts and never again. What you want to do here instead is use a function to run your `get()` statements before you destroy.

We can accomplish this by simply adding a new function and changing the button command to call that function.

I also changed your code to better fit the PEP8 standard so you can see what that would look like.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("DESIGN OF LINED CANAL")
v1 = tk.IntVar()
v2 = tk.IntVar()

def ok_button_function():
    global shape, hyd
    shape=v1.get()
    hyd=v2.get()
    root.destroy()
    
tk.Label(root, text="What is the shape of your Canal? ").pack()

tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Trapezoidal", variable=v1, value=0).pack()
tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Rectangular", variable=v1, value=1).pack()
tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Triangular", variable=v1, value=2).pack()

tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Yes", variable=v2, value=0).pack()
tk.Radiobutton(root, text="No", variable=v2, value=1).pack()

tk.Button(root, text="OK", bg="red", command=ok_button_function).pack()

root.mainloop()

print("shape", shape)
print("hyd", hyd)
```

Before app is closed:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: @SUJITKUMARSamal Your welcome :D. If my Answer solved your problem please select the check mark next to my answer to show your issue has been resolved.